# How can I define a zero-or-one-to-zero-or-one self-referencing relation?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

Consider the following table. A record can have a related *original* and a record can only be the *original* of one other record.

```sql
create table dbo.foo
(
    id int identity
        constraint pk primary key
    ,name nvarchar(max) not null
    ,original int null
        constraint fk_original foreign key references dbo.foo(id)
)
create unique index ix_original on dbo.foo(original) where original is not null

insert into dbo.foo values('bar1', null)
insert into dbo.foo values('baz1', null)
insert into dbo.foo values('bar2', 1)
insert into dbo.foo values('baz2', 2)
--insert into dbo.foo values('baz3', 2) /* violates the unique constraint */

select * from dbo.foo
/*
id name original
-- ---- --------
1  bar1 NULL
2  baz1 NULL
3  bar2 1
4  baz2 2
*/
```

Generating an EDMX creates an entity with 2 navigation properties:

- foo1, Collection of foo, * (Many)
- foo2, Instance of foo, 0..1 (Zero or One)

`foo1` is a collection of records having said record as the original. `foo2` is a reference to the original. The following code demonstrates this:

```cs
var items = context.foo.ToList();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", item.id, item.name, item.original);
    foreach (var related in item.foo1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("related\t{0}", related.id);
    }
    if (item.foo2 != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("original\t{0}", item.foo2.id);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

```
1       bar1
related 3

2       baz1
related 4

3       bar2    1
original        1

4       baz2    2
original        2
```

So even though I specified that a record can only be the *original* of one other record, EF insists that this should be a collection. When I try to change `foo1` to *0..1 (Zero or One)*, I get this error:

> Running transformation: Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'foo1' in
>   relationship 'fk_original'. Because the Dependent Role properties are
>   not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the
>   Dependent Role must be *.

Are there any additional changes that need to be done, did I make an incorrect assumption or can EF not handle this situation?